# Difference between two Lamba Expressions in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am trying to understand the difference between these two Lambda Expressions within LINQ Join method.

The two lines I do not understand are those starting with `Function(aaa) ...` and `Function(bbb) ...`.

1. Why do I have explicitly name the field `Name` in the second example for both `aaa` and `bbb`while in the first one it works without it?
2. On the other hand in the first example `bbb.Owner` points to `Owner` field of `Pet` but it does not tell that `Name` field of the `Person` shall be used to make the join.

First example (comes from .Net Framework documentation with variable names changed):

```
Structure Person
    Public Name As String
    Public SecondName As String
End Structure

Structure Pet
    Public Name As String
    Public Owner As Person
End Structure

Dim magnus As New Person With {.Name = "Hedlund, Magnus"}
Dim terry As New Person With {.Name = "Adams, Terry"}
Dim charlotte As New Person With {.Name = "Weiss, Charlotte"}

Dim barley As New Pet With {.Name = "Barley", .Owner = terry}
Dim boots As New Pet With {.Name = "Boots", .Owner = terry}
Dim whiskers As New Pet With {.Name = "Whiskers", .Owner = charlotte}
Dim daisy As New Pet With {.Name = "Daisy", .Owner = magnus}

Dim people As New List(Of Person)(New Person() {magnus, terry, charlotte})
Dim pets As New List(Of Pet)(New Pet() {barley, boots, whiskers, daisy})

Dim query = people.Join(pets,
    Function(aaa) aaa,
    Function(bbb) bbb.Owner,
    Function(ccc, ddd) _
        New With {.OwnerName1 = ccc.Name, .Pet1 = ddd.Name})
```

Second example (my code)

```
Structure MyObject
    Public Name As String
    Public Value As Integer
End Structure

Dim Test1 As New List(Of MyObject) From {
    New MyObject With {.Name = "a", .Value = 1},
    New MyObject With {.Name = "b", .Value = 2},
    New MyObject With {.Name = "c", .Value = 3}
    }

Dim Test2 As New List(Of MyObject) From {
    New MyObject With {.Name = "a", .Value = 11},
    New MyObject With {.Name = "b", .Value = 22},
    New MyObject With {.Name = "c", .Value = 33}
    }

Dim Joined = Test1.Join(Test2,
   Function(aaa) aaa.Name,
   Function(bbb) bbb.Name,
   Function(ccc, ddd) New With {
       .Name1 = ccc.Name,
       .Value1 = ccc.Value,
       .Value2 = ddd.Value})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__), you'll see that the first function is the selector for the outer sequence and the second is the selector for the inner sequence.

The value form the inner and outer selectors must have the same type (`TKey`) and will be compared using the default comparer for that type (there's an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___2__) that allows you to pass a comparer).

The third function is the result selector that receives a `TOuter` and a `TInner` instances that match according to the selected keys and returns a `TResult` value.

So, in the first example `TKey` is `Person`. `outerSelector` and `innerSelector` must return a `Person`, thus `aaa` and `bbb`.

On the second example you chose to compare the `Name` field and not the entire `MyObject` structure.